# How to display years as well as months and days by using amdifference

Tags: angularjs

**{{perworks.FromDate | amDifference : perworks.ToDate : 'years' }}Year(s)**

Comment: What problem are you facing with this?

Comment: This Working Fine Display Years but I want to display year, months as well as days eg. 31-12-2014    TO    02-02-2016  ( 1 Year(s)  ) but I want 1 year, 1 month, 2 days output